How to set a "paste delay per line" with telnet or equivalent?
When working on my Windows PC, I use TeraTerm to connect to a "console" interface of an embedded program over UART. This console is a very simple I/O implementation with no command-line memory.
When entering a command at the console, the system takes some time to perform it and then prompts again for user input. To run repeated command sequences, I copy a bunch of commands from a text editor and paste them into the console.
The problem is that when using simple telnet or a similar program, the system performs the first command in the block and by the time control is back at the console, the following commands pasted are lost.
With TeraTerm, I can define a delay between pasted lines, which solves this problem:

However, this program is not available on Linux. I could not find an equivalent setting with simple telnet. Installing PuTTY on the Linux machine, but could not find an equivalent setting there as well.

Is there such setting in telnet?
Is there such setting in PuTTY?
What terminal emulators for Linux provide such functionality?


pv -qlL 2 | telnet … or maybe better rlwrap sh -c 'pv -qlL 2 | telnet …' with bracketed paste enabled. The problem is telnet is now reading from a pipe, not directly from the terminal; this may limit its functionality. Do you really need telnet? (see this for context). How do you connect telnet to the UART? Maybe you just need a raw connection like with socat STDIO /dev/ttyUSB0,b19200,raw. If so, then rlwrap sh -c 'pv -qlL 2 | socat …' will possibly work reasonably well. So, how is it?

It sounds like what you may want to use in Linux is a program called expect.  It can be set up to wait for a prompt to appear and then send the next line of input.  That way, you won't have a race happening between the text input you want to send and the processing of the previous command.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect
Here's a discussion around an SSH example that may map onto your use case as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101879/bash-expect-script-for-ssh
Similar behavior is possible in TeraTerm with its own built-in scripting language.
